# currently viewed country in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, countries

I need a way to figure out what country (if any) the user is currently viewing on the map.
If multiple countries are view'd just return "".
I've been working on this for a while, and know how to use the reverse geocoder, however, that is not an option as it would be **far** to many requests.

My best bet is to use some boxes around the countries, and then check if the map center is in any of them.

So in short:

i need a list of countries and there corners cordinates.

i need a way to loop through to find out which one is viewed

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure why you can't just get the map center and then reverse geocode that for the country underneath it. Such as:

[image]

Even though Canada is in the top part of this map, the center is in the United States.

If you want to check for multiple countries, what I did was create a grid pattern that looks at 9 (or 4 or 16 or whatever you want) evenly distributed points on the map and looks at the countries under each point. I've noticed that sometimes the reverse geocoder returns null even within a county, usually when the marker falls on an uninhabitated region.

[image: grid map example]

If you would like code examples for either of these I will include them.